# could have + past participle to express past possibility that come true

Tags: modal-verbs

> "I’m happy because you could have won the race."

Could we say this sentence to a person who won a race?

Comment: The use of *could* means that they did ***not*** win the race. What you could use is *I'm happy because you **had the chance to win** the race.* They had the chance, whether they won it or not. So, the sentence is true regardless of the actual outcome.

Comment: Could we use the sentence I gave in question in case when we  didn’t know whether the person won the race or not? only we know that the person had the opportunity to win

Comment: It's theoretically possible (the syntax doesn't completely preclude it), but it would almost never happen. The sentence in the question would normally only be used if you know they lost. If you know they won, or you don't know either way, then other wording would be used.